# montgomery reduction multiplicative identity

Tags: elliptic-curves, montgomery-multiplication

How do you figure out the multiplicative and additive identity with respects to R?

I pick some R such that gcd(R, N) = 1 where N is the size of the group.

Given some field element x in the group, I do x' = xR mod N

How would I figure out the multiplicative identity `m` such that `x' * m = x'`

and the additive identity `a` such that x' + a = x'` ?

Comment: Did you try to transfer 1 into Montgomery Domain by  $1 R \mod n$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The additive identity is $0$, as usual.

The multiplicative identity is the Montgomery representative for $1$, namely $1\cdot R \bmod N = R \bmod N$, just like the Montgomery representative for any other element $x$ is $x\cdot R \bmod N$.